# Vue.js src searching localhost instead of file system

Tags: vue.js

I have an image whose src I'm trying to change when it is clicked.

```
<b-img :id="favorite" src="~/static/svg/favorite.svg" @click="iconClicked(favorite)" right />
```

And down under export default, I have

```
methods: {
        iconClicked(name: any) {
            (<HTMLImageElement> document.getElementById(name))!.src="~/static/svg/favoriteAlternate.svg";
        }
    }
```

When I run my code at `localhost:3000`, I get a 404 error, and the code appears to be searching `localhost:3000/~/static/svg/favoriteAlternate.svg` instead of my local file system.

Why might this be? What should I do to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: use a model for the image src instead, then on click change the model value, or toggle between 2 elements with v-if/else, using getElementById seems like an odd way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things wrong here.

First, you shouldn't be manually interacting with the DOM like that – Vue "owns" the DOM and you should leave it to Vue to change.

When Vue compiles the template, it treats the `src` attribute specially by loading the file on disk it refers to *through webpack*. But then when you manually change the element's `src` attribute like that, the new file it references was never bundled by webpack so it won't load.

You need to `require`/`import` both images so they get bundled. Then swap between them using a binding on the `src` attribute.

Something like:

```html
<img :src="src">
```

```js
// These are not javascript files, however webpack will bundle them
// and export the correct src you should use to refer to them
import FavoriteImage from '~/static/svg/favorite.svg'
import FavoriteAltImage from '~/static/svg/favoriteAlternate.svg'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      src: FavoriteImage,
    }
  },

  methods: {
    iconClicked() {
      this.src = FavoriteAltImage
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!